# Paypal Sandbox IPN "Email does not match seller"

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to create a paypal subscription button with paypal sandbox. I have created the dev account, created sandbox business and test accounts. Logged into my business test account, went to merchant services -> my saved buttons.

Found the subscription button and copied the code.

I have uploaded the form to my codeigniter controller at: http://422clients.com/ftg/paypal/test

I am using this paypal IPN library for codeigniter: https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn

I am using unmodified controller code for now to handle the IPN response because it writes it to the database just fine for testing:

```
function ipn()
    {
        $this->load->library('PayPal_IPN'); // Load the library

        // Try to get the IPN data.
        if ($this->paypal_ipn->validateIPN())
        {
            // Succeeded, now let's extract the order
            $this->paypal_ipn->extractOrder();

            // And we save the order now (persist and extract are separate because you might only want to persist the order in certain circumstances).
            $this->paypal_ipn->saveOrder();

            // Now let's check what the payment status is and act accordingly
            if ($this->paypal_ipn->orderStatus == PayPal_IPN::PAID)
            {
                //Enable database subscription...
            }
        }
        else // Just redirect to the root URL
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when i click the button on the site and pay with my sandbox test account everything looks totally fine and the payment goes through, but when I look in my database it says: Status: ERROR.

Reason Field says: email business_test@422studios.com does not match seller

business_test@422studios.com is the sandbox account that i generated the button from.

I'm totally lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config file, make sure you have this:

```
$config['paypal_ipn_sandbox_settings'] = array(
    'email' => 'business_test@422studios.com',
    'url' => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
    'debug' => TRUE
);
```

And that you pass this value in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="business_test@422studios.com">
```